# CanvasAutorize - redirection to facebook permissions dialog clears the request_ids query string sent when user accepts an app request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

When a user accepts my application request, the user is redirected to my app page with a parameter request_ids which is the request id info for that application request. The problem is that my app page has the [CanvasAuthorize] attribute that redirects the user to the permissions grant dialog and when user accepts it it returns the app entry point, but during this transfer i lose the request_ids querystring and cannot use the request id in my code.

How can I avoid this? What are the recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? I know in version 5 the new oauth system is being used (rather than the php dialog used in v4) which is supposed to preserve the query string.

Comment: @el_tone: I'm using the 4.2.1 but i will change to 5 when the final release comes out... little skeptic with the 5. I overcome this by redirecting manually the action to an empty template with the a javascript code window.location = facebook_auth_url. Although is not the best, preferably way, it works for me know until i get th v5.

Comment: v5 is very stable so you should have no worries about using it in a production scenario. Make sure you write that out as an answer and mark it out as resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I overcome this by redirecting manually the ActionResult to an empty template with the following javascript autogen code:

```
public static string GetCanvasRedirectHtml(string url)
        {
            var fbApp = new FacebookApp();

            string authUrl = string.Format("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}", fbApp.AppId, url, requiredAppPermissions);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
            }

            return "<html><head>" +
                   "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n" +
                    "top.location = \"" + authUrl + "\";\n" +
                    "</script>" +
                   "</head><body></body></html>";
        }
```

This would give me back the access_code that I would later on exchange for the accesstoken and get a valid session.

HTH someone!